# How to close the mobile navbar after clicking

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm making a website and need some help with the navbar for a mobile device.
Basicly I want to close the nav when clicked for example ["Destaques"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA1Pf.jpg). All i need to do is remove the class "opened" when I clicked at any link.
since it's only one page, it never redirects to any other page.

I've tried to change with the function .click and getElement by Id but didnt work, so I click on `<a>` but want to change the class for `<nav>` from `<nav class="nav1 opened"` to `<nav class="nav1"`
Here's an example of my code.

```
<nav class="nav1" id="nav-mobile">
    <a class="mobile_menu_close"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="flex">
                 <ul class="nav1_links">
                        <li class="links-header"><a href="#contact"> Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
</nav>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this, I've tried probably 20 diferent ways but haven't found a awnser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis,

I have set up some code for you that will add/remove `.open` class.  All in regular JS.  This can be applied to your hamburger icon instead of the button for the open click event and each `<li>` for the close event.

[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iisrael/j8n1w2bL/24/)

Comment: the only error on you code the getElementById, on my code didn't reach the Id with that, but if you put 

´´$("#yourId").removeClass("yourClass");
e.preventDefault() /*ignores actual link*/´´

It works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

That won't happen because when you click on `<a>` tags that contains `href` Attribute, page will refresh and JavaScript Codes won't work
you should use a "close button" using`<button>` tag instead of `<a>` tags

Comment: but my page doesnt refresh, it just goes to the id of a ´<a>´ with the name of the href

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you could do this

```
$( ".nav1" ).removeClass("opened");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $(this).closest(".nav1").removeClass("opened");
})
```